# javascript date format with data linked from sql with php

Tags: javascript, php, sql

how am i able to get the correct date format and subtract two dates in javascript? i have both sql and php used to get both date values in my table to js. my "createddate" and "expirationdate" have year, month, day, hour, minute and second. i need to the time difference working and start a countdown from there. also, in my current code, the display shows "NaNd NaNh NaNm NaNs"

Javascript:

```
var x = setInterval(function() {

  var time_createddate     = "<?php  echo($lstOrders['createddate']); ?>";
  var time_expirationdate  = "<?php  echo($lstOrders['expirationdate']); ?>";

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = time_createddate - time_expirationdate;
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.querySelectorAll('.c_countdown').forEach(function(elem){
    elem.innerHTML = innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  })

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("c_countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

[image: sql]

Comment: What values do $lstOrders['createddate'] and $lstOrders['expirationdate'] contain?

Comment: updated my question with an sql screenshot. 'createddate' and 'expirationdate' have datetime format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS

Comment: Then `time_createddate - time_expirationdate` doesn’t make much sense to begin with. Subtraction works with actual numbers; a date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS` isn’t one.

Comment: what i am trying to do is get both dates, and subtract them from each other and get the hours remaining in order to start a dynamic countdown.